# Unable to generate device simulation libraries from Quartus Prime

Tags: fpga, simulation, quartus, library

I am using Quartus 18.1. I am trying to generate device simulation libraries as per the procedure here:
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/programmable/support/support-resources/knowledge-base/solutions/rd06182013_21.html

I also tried to use the GUI that comes with Quartus to do the same. However, I end up getting error every time.

Here is the output:

```
C:\My_Designs\Test\counter>quartus_sh --simlib_comp -tool questasim -family cycloneive -language vhdl -gen_only
Info: *******************************************************************
Info: Running Quartus Prime Shell
    Info: Version 18.1.0 Build 625 09/12/2018 SJ Standard Edition
    Info: Copyright (C) 2018  Intel Corporation. All rights reserved.
    Info: Your use of Intel Corporation's design tools, logic functions
    Info: and other software and tools, and its AMPP partner logic
    Info: functions, and any output files from any of the foregoing
    Info: (including device programming or simulation files), and any
    Info: associated documentation or information are expressly subject
    Info: to the terms and conditions of the Intel Program License
    Info: Subscription Agreement, the Intel Quartus Prime License Agreement,
    Info: the Intel FPGA IP License Agreement, or other applicable license
    Info: agreement, including, without limitation, that your use is for
    Info: the sole purpose of programming logic devices manufactured by
    Info: Intel and sold by Intel or its authorized distributors.  Please
    Info: refer to the applicable agreement for further details.
    Info: Processing started: Fri Jan 01 23:54:43 2021
Info: Command: quartus_sh --simlib_comp -tool questasim -family cycloneive -language vhdl -gen_only
Info: Quartus(args): -tool questasim -family cycloneive -language vhdl -gen_only
------------------------------------------------
invalid command name "cmdline::getFunctionOptions"
    while executing
"unknown_original cmdline::getFunctionOptions ::quartus(args) {{family.arg #_default_# {The name of the Quartus Prime device family, without any spaces..."
    ("eval" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"eval unknown_original $cmd $args"
    (procedure "::unknown" line 7)
    invoked from within
"cmdline::getFunctionOptions ::quartus(args) $function_opts"
    invoked from within
"array set optshash [cmdline::getFunctionOptions ::quartus(args) $function_opts]"
    (file "c:/intelfpga/18.1/quartus/common/tcl/internal/simlib_comp.tcl" line 1446)
------------------------------------------------
Error (23031): Evaluation of Tcl script c:/intelfpga/18.1/quartus/common/tcl/internal/simlib_comp.tcl unsuccessful
Error: Quartus Prime Shell was unsuccessful. 1 error, 0 warnings
    Error: Peak virtual memory: 4717 megabytes
    Error: Processing ended: Fri Jan 01 23:54:43 2021
    Error: Elapsed time: 00:00:00
    Error: Total CPU time (on all processors): 00:00:01
```

I do not understand why this is happening at all. I would be grateful if anyone can shed some light on this.

Comment: What I do is run the do file created with the simulation model of the ip that I need to simulate.  You need vendor libraries only for the ip or gate level sim.

Comment: Are you trying to get the script or trying to compile the entire simulation library? -gen_only option is to generate the script. Maybe, you can use the GUI and give the path of the sim tool before trying again.

Comment: GUI gives the Error (23031) as well

Comment: It will be good if you add the screenshot from the GUI, not the error, the settings you've used to generate the sim libs.